# Transactional rollback for specific inserts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Hi have a requirement in which i am reading one file blow is the example how file looks like

File.xls

id scode value1 value2 value3 ------ so on

0  acdss  12     6       14   ----- no exception

1  acxx  0.14    5      12    ----- exception  -- rollback

2  cxsas 52.2    24     21    ----  no exception

for  each row i have to insert/update  the data into 3 different tables after performing some business logic

so my insert/update  is running in a for loop and for each row.

Problem is if any exception occur while inserting/updating the data into database  for any row i want to rollback the insertion from all the 3 tables for that specific row and continue the insertion for rest of the row 
As mentioned in file example for id 0 and 2 there was no exception, data should be inserted in all  the 3 table and for id 1 it should rollback all the insertion .
 i am using jdbcTemplate for my db operation 
Below if the sample code which i have implemented

```
    class writer {
    public void persistData() {
        // code to read file and created object for each table
        // size of file here is 3 so loop is running 3 times and table1Object
        // and table2Object and table3Object has rows to be inserted into
        // database table A,B,C
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            service.persistData(table1Object[i], table2Object[i], table3Oject[i]);

        }
    }
}

class service {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW, readOnly = false)
    public void persistData(ob1,ob2,ob3){
        dao.insertionOrUpadteForTableA(ob1);
        dao.insertionOrUpadteForTableB(ob2);
        dao.insertionOrUpadteForTableC(ob3);

    }
}
```

using this approach my whole transaction is getting rollback can any one suggest me how we can achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

Put a `try`/`catch` around the service call in order to continue the line-by-line file processing in `persistData` even in case of transaction errors:

```
public void persistData() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       try {
           service.persistData(table1Object[i], table2Object[i], table3Oject[i]);
       } catch (TransactionException ex) {
           // handle exception
       }
    }
}
```

`TransactionException` is a `RuntimeException` of [Spring Tx](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-strategies) in context of database transactions.

In your example, the default transaction propagation mode `REQUIRED` will suffice.

```
class service {
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void persistData(ob1,ob2,ob3) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Please provide some additional explanation for downvoting. That would help me to improve my answer. Thanks.